# Selecting a range with CKEditor - wierd behaviour

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, range

I am trying to select a specific range within an edited element, but everytime the cursor jumps to the very end of it and I can't figure out why.

I am creating my range and selecting it like this

```
var tempRange = editor.createRange();
tempRange.setStart(tempRange.root, 20);
tempRange.setEnd(tempRange.root, 20);
editor.getSelection().selectRanges([tempRange]);
```

After executing this the cursor jumps to the end of the element's text. There are no errors. The wierd thing is that before `.selectRanges()` the `startOffset` and `endOffset` are correctly set to 20, as I set them, although when I look at the range object after the `.selectRanges()` they are both set to 4.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening, please?

Edit @oleq:

editor.editable().getHtml():

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<sup>1</sup> yada yada, something else and more stuff.
```

Comment: Provide HTML inside of the editor (`editor.editable().getHtml()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting off, you should take a look on [W3 DOM Range specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Definitions). And to be precise,  that diagram is what should interest you the most:

[image]

Then, if you consider the following HTML in your editable area of CKEditor (I assume there's no `<p>` there, right?)

```
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<sup>1</sup> yada yada, something else and more stuff
</body>
```

you'll probably notice that the following code

```
tempRange.setStart(tempRange.root, 20);
tempRange.setEnd(tempRange.root, 20);
```

makes no sense because `<body>` (`tempRange.root`) has only 3 children (a text node, `<sup>` and another text node). What you actually want to do is something like that:

```
tempRange.setStart(tempRange.root.getFirst(), 20);
tempRange.collapse();
tempRange.select();
```

To prove it correct, call immediately

```
tempRange.insertNode( new CKEDITOR.dom.text( '^' ) );
```

and editor contents will become

```
Lorem ipsum dolor si^t amet<sup>1</sup> yada yada, something else and more stuff.
```

---

#### A bunch of helpful links to CKEditor API:

- [`CKEDITOR.dom.range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range)

  - [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.collapse()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-collapse)
  - [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.select()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-select)
  - [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.setStart()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-setStart)
  - [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.setStartAt()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-setStartAt)
- [`CKEDITOR.dom.selection`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection)